# Cannot access Linux in dual boot because system boots straight to Windows without showing the grub menu?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-16.04

I have linux and windows installed after upgrading to windows 10 , when I reboot the system there is no grub screen to select the system I want , it just gooes direct to windows 10.

> Cannot access Linux in dual boot because system boots straight to
>   Windows without showing the grub menu?

Here is solution I have tried

In windows I run  `cmd` as administrator and run the follwoing :

`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

After I reboot the system still boots straight to windows 10, If I want to go to linux I need to go to setting ->recovery -> advance restart and select the ubuntu .

What do I need to change to get dual boot system working??

Comment: You should be able to change it permanently in UEFI settings.

Comment: http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia how to do that?

Comment: Do you know what UEFI is? It's what many wrongly still refer to as "BIOS" which is not but does the same. But like the old BIOS, how to access and the specific UEFI settings are unique for the hardware brand/model. Please check your user's manual or do an online search.